# Writing read_jpeg and decode_jpeg functions for TensorFlow Lite C++

Tags: c++, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite, image-classification

TensorFlow Lite has a good C++ image classification example in their repo, [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/lite/examples/label_image).
However, I'm working with .jpeg and this example is restricted to decoding .bmp images with [bitmap_helpers.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/lite/examples/label_image).

I'm trying to create my own jpeg decoder but I'm not well versed in image processing so could use some help. I'm reusing [this jpeg decoder](https://h4ck3r.net/2009/12/02/mini-jpeg-decoder/) as a third party helper library. In the example's bmp decoding, I don't quite understand what's the deal with calculating [row_sizes](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b5309200b275d3a18f9f498c6bf8904fef1bbaa7/tensorflow/lite/examples/label_image/bitmap_helpers.cc#L107) and taking in the bytes array [after the header](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b5309200b275d3a18f9f498c6bf8904fef1bbaa7/tensorflow/lite/examples/label_image/bitmap_helpers.cc#L107). Could anyone shed some light into how this would apply for a jpeg decoder? Or, even better, is there already a C++ decode_jpeg function hiding somewhere which I have not found?

The final implementation must be in TensorFlow Lite in C++.

thank you so much!

**EDIT:**

Below is what I have so far. I don't get the same confidence values as when I use the Python example of the image classifier for the same input image and tflite model so this is a clear indication that something is wrong. I essentially copy and pasted the row_size calculation from read_bmp without understanding it so I suspect that might be the issue. What is row_size meant to represent?

```
std::vector<uint8_t> decode_jpeg(const uint8_t* input, int row_size, int width, int height) {

    // Channels will always be 3. Hardcode it for now.
    int channels = 3;

    // The output that wil lcontain the data for TensorFlow to process.
    std::vector<uint8_t> output(height * width * channels);

    // Go through every pixel of the image.
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            int src_pos;
            int dst_pos;

            for(int j = 0; j < width; j++) {

                    src_pos = i * row_size + j * channels;
                    dst_pos = (i * width + j) * channels;

                    // Put RGB channel data into the output array.
                    output[dst_pos] = input[src_pos + 2];
                    output[dst_pos + 1] = input[src_pos + 1];
                    output[dst_pos + 2] = input[src_pos];
            }
    }

    return output;
}

std::vector<uint8_t> read_jpeg(const std::string& input_jpeg_name, int* width, int* height, Settings* s) {

    // Size and buffer.
    size_t size;
    unsigned char *buf;

    // Open the input file.
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen(input_jpeg_name.c_str(), "rb");
    if (!f) {
            if (s->verbose) LOG(INFO) << "Error opening the input file\n";
            exit(-1);
    }

    // Read the file.
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);

    // Ge tthe file size.
    size = ftell(f);

    // Get file data into buffer.
    buf = (unsigned char*)malloc(size);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    size_t read = fread(buf, 1, size, f);
    
    // Close the file.
    fclose(f);

    // Decode the file.
    Decoder decoder(buf, size);
    if (decoder.GetResult() != Decoder::OK)
    {
            if (s->verbose) LOG(INFO) << "Error decoding the input file\n";
            exit(-1);
    }

    // Get the image from the decoded file.
    unsigned char* img = decoder.GetImage();

    // Get image width and height.
    *width = decoder.GetWidth();
    *height = decoder.GetHeight();

    // TODO: Understand what this row size means. Don't just copy and paste.
    const int row_size = (8 * *channels * *width + 31) / 32 * 4;

    // Decode the JPEG.
    return decode_jpeg(img, row_size, *width, *height);
}
```

Comment: Can you convert them to BMP ahead of time using ImageMagick or similar, as suggested in the jpeg decoder link you give? If so, you could use the example as-is. If not and if TensorFlow Lite only groks BMP, you might search for a more full-featured imaging library to assist you in getting bitmap data out of a different file format so you can focus on the details of your algorithm. ImageMagick may be a candidate.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Unfortunately this is not an option because of the of heavy constraints in the operating environment with respect to processing complexity and disk space. I must decode the jpg files as they are given.

Comment: You can still decode it at runtime while using a different library that gives you results closer to what you can use, no? It's not clear to me why you need to do the steps for JPEGs that it currently does for BMPs. The two formats won't have the same header or structure. Try to show exactly what problem you are trying to solve. Does TFL operate on raw RGB arrays in memory? Does it accept an image load function that you have to implement to meet their spec? Please post (excerpts of rather than links to) the code you are having trouble with and the interface you are trying to meet.

Comment: Thank you for following up! My understanding is that I only need to fetch the RGB values for each pixel and put them in an output array, hence I need the image data without the header. I understand that decoder.GetImage() from [mini-jpeg-decoder](https://h4ck3r.net/2009/12/02/mini-jpeg-decoder/) skips header data so I should be left with just the image bytes to decode. My understanding may be wrong! I really cannot install something like ImageMagick in the target environment, it needs to be as lightweight as possible. I included some excerpts in my original post. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Library you are using is already handling decoding for you, decoder.getImage() contains raw rgb data. You do not need to calculate any sizes whatsoever.

Stuff like row_size is something specific to BMP file format. BMP files may contain some padding bytes in addition to pixel color data, the code was handling that stuff.

Also BMP files store pixel values in BGR order, that is why you have reverse ordering in your original code:

```
// Put RGB channel data into the output array.
output[dst_pos] = input[src_pos + 2];
output[dst_pos + 1] = input[src_pos + 1];
output[dst_pos + 2] = input[src_pos];
```

Below code should be working for you (note that decode_jpeg function does not perform any decoding):

```
std::vector<uint8_t> decode_jpeg(const uint8_t* input, int width, int height) {

    // Channels will always be 3. Hardcode it for now.
    int channels = 3;

    // The output that will contain the data for TensorFlow to process.
    std::vector<uint8_t> output(height * width * channels);

    //  Copy pixel data to output
    for (size_t i = 0; i < height*width*channels; ++i)
    {
        output[i] = input[i];
    }

    
    return output;
}

std::vector<uint8_t> read_jpeg(const std::string& input_jpeg_name, int* width, int* height, Settings* s) {

    // Size and buffer.
    size_t size;
    unsigned char *buf;

    // Open the input file.
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen(input_jpeg_name.c_str(), "rb");
    if (!f) {
            if (s->verbose) LOG(INFO) << "Error opening the input file\n";
            exit(-1);
    }

    // Read the file.
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);

    // Ge tthe file size.
    size = ftell(f);

    // Get file data into buffer.
    buf = (unsigned char*)malloc(size);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    size_t read = fread(buf, 1, size, f);
    
    // Close the file.
    fclose(f);

    // Decode the file.
    Decoder decoder(buf, size);
    if (decoder.GetResult() != Decoder::OK)
    {
            if (s->verbose) LOG(INFO) << "Error decoding the input file\n";
            exit(-1);
    }

    // Get the image from the decoded file.
    unsigned char* img = decoder.GetImage();

    // Get image width and height.
    *width = decoder.GetWidth();
    *height = decoder.GetHeight();

    // Decode the JPEG.
    return decode_jpeg(img, *width, *height);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the image processing lesson, all clear! So decode_jpeg should just be renamed to something like to_vector. Or maybe I could use std::transform instead.

However, my confidence levels still don't match when using the same image and model with the python implementation of [label_image](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b0784e587b62eec6967196b745bba4db3a90ab0c/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image.py) so something's still up!

Comment: Maybe first compare some pixel values of C++ code and python code (at arbitrary pixel positions) to make sure you got the RGB values correct. If they are same, there is probably a difference between train codes.

Comment: @Georges Here is an example code using your jpeg decoding library to access pixels values of the image. I tested with an simple 10x10 image and seems working. https://pastebin.com/c4ugM8fe (for some reason headers seem missing to me, they are stdio.h, stdlib.h, string.h).

Comment: That was above and beyond of what was needed. Clearly you have answered my original question. My differences in confidence levels is another issue. Thank you so much!